# How to add word or nimber in stoke with Ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml, jitsi

I have a code

```
  - name: Ansible replace string example
    replace:
      path: /etc/jitsi/videobridge/sip-communicator.properties contains
      regexp: 'shard'
      replace: "shard-1"
```

But it does not work :(

I have a stroke:

```
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard.HOSTNAME=localhost
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard.DOMAIN=auth.jc.name.com
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard.USERNAME=name
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard.PASSWORD=Hfr*7462
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard.MUC_JIDS=JvbBredjoy@internal.auth.jc.name.com
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard.MUC_NICKNAME=7896aee5-fgre-4b02-4569-0bcc75ed1d0d
```

in file `/etc/jitsi/videobridge/sip-communicator.properties`

I should to add after word `shard` symbol "-" and number (**1, 2, 3**) etc. For example `org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-1.HOSTNAME=localhost`

Before of this, I should to check - if line `org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-1.HOSTNAME=localhost` contain word `shard-1` then we rename to `shard-2` and etc.

Comment: you have shard on all lines?

Comment: Did you intend to include ` contains` at the end of your `path:`?

Comment: I have other lines in the same file, but they are without word "shard".

Answer (score 0):

to answer to your problem, i'd use a custom filter plugin to create the new value which replaces the old values:

you create a folder **filter_plugins** in your playbook folder (i have named the file **myfilters.py** and the filter **buildvalue**)

the filter: to avoid memory leaks, use 'with' to open file (thanks to @mdaniel)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'buildvalue': self.buildvalue
        }

    def buildvalue(self, nfile, srch):
        found = False
        with open(nfile, 'r') as f: 
            lines = f.readlines()
            for line in lines: 
                x = re.search(srch + '-*[0-9]*', line)
                if x != None:
                    found = True
                    break

        if found:        
            rep = srch + ('-1' if '-' not in x.group() else '-' + str((int(x.group().split('-')[1]) + 1))) 
        else:
            rep = srch

        return rep
```

the playbook:

```
  tasks:
    - name: replace
      ansible.builtin.replace:
        path: "{{ filename }}"
        regexp: "{{ search }}-*[0-9]*"
        replace: "{{ newvalue }}"
      vars:
        filename: 'files/fileregex.txt'
        search: 'shard'
        newvalue: "{{ filename | buildvalue(search)  }}"
```

Comment: Cool! Could you please tell me, how it will be works when I have default lines, for example

org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard.USERNAME=name
(without any numbers)

Comment: Without number, the newvalue will be shard-1

Comment: Thank you. One more question.
For example I have 2 servers (or more) and I need to that, on one of them was line

`org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard.HOSTNAME=localhost
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard.DOMAIN=auth.jc.name.com
etc

on other server:

`org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-1.HOSTNAME=localhost
org.jitsi.videobridge.xmpp.user.shard-1.DOMAIN=auth.jc.name.com

etc

Can I did this with your code? And I should to do this only with python, can I do this with only Ansible code?

Comment: if i understand your question, on first server, shard becomes shard-1 on second server shard-1 becomes shard-2 .. its the job doing by my custom filter. To do that only with Ansible, what do you mean? ansible contains lots of filters written in python, do you do that with the filters already including in ansible, maybe i have not tried because that seems to be more difficult than a simple custom filter..